# Python child dataclass with different parameter order

Tags: python, refactoring, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to bring an old code base up to date.

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Type:
  size: int

...

class Pointer(Type):
  def __init__(self, basetype: Type, size):
```

I'd like to use frozen data classes for both classes, but I have a problem with the order of the parameters in the `Pointer` constructor.

When I change `Pointer` into a dataclass, the automatically generarted `__init__` method would append the new parameter, changeing the signature from `Pointer(type, size)` to `Pointer(size, type)`. However, I would like to keep the order since there are more than 800 places in my code base generating a pointer type.
e
Is it possible do to this with dataclasses?

Comment: dataclasses are a tool, not a goal. Use them if they actually help, not just for the sake of using them.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you did to make the order change, but can't you change it back yourself?

Comment: @Guy when you inherit from another dataclass, your new field automatically gets appended to the fields of the other class in the constructor :/

Comment: @Nordwald well I can't reproduce this, and it still doesn't answer why can't you just change the order yourself.

Comment: @Guy Please provide some example on how to change the order of the parameters of the constructor of a frozen dataclass - that would be exactly what I need

Comment: @Nordwald example of what? just change it as any other piece of code you want to change. And why do you have the base class as parameter in `__init__` anyway? it should be `self`.

Comment: @Guy I want to transform Pointer into a data class (where I can not do a manual constructor), while maintaining the order of the parameters. Self missing here is a mistake - I'm gonna fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to have the constructor accept an aribtary order of parameters, but it is not very pretty.

While it is true you can not set the fields in the `__init__` method with assignments, you can still use `__setattr__` kinda how dataclasses work internally.

The constructor in this example would look like this:

```
    def __init__(self, basetype: Type, size: int):
        """Custom constructor to change the order of the parameters."""
        object.__setattr__(self, "basetype", basetype)
        object.__setattr__(self, "size", size)
```